# Parallel(methods) execution with dependsOn running in unexpected order

Tags: java, testng

I'm trying to run the following tests with `parallel="methods"` attribute in my testng suite in xml.

```
public class TestClass {
    @Test(groups = { "groupA" })
    public void method1() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Starting method1");
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 10); // wait 10 seconds
        System.out.println("Ending method1");
    }
    @Test(groups = { "groupB" })
    public void method2() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Starting method2");
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 2); // wait 2 seconds
        System.out.println("Ending method2");
    }
    @Test(groups = "groupB", dependsOnGroups = { "groupA" })
    public void method3() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Starting method3");
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 2); // wait 2 seconds
        System.out.println("Ending method3");
    }
}
```

**`testng.xml`** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.testngGroup.TestClass"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I would expect the following results:

```
Starting method1
Starting method2
Ending method2
Ending method1
Starting method3
Ending method3
```

but I'm getting these results:

```
Starting method1
Starting method2
Ending method2
Starting method3
Ending method3
Ending method1
```

Method3 is not waiting for method1 to complete. It appears to wait for method2 to complete, but I'm not sure why.

---

***Edit(np)***  -

Went through the documentation looking for what [parallel running](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests) actually does. It conveys  -

> **parallel="methods"**: TestNG will run all your test methods in separate
>   threads. Dependent methods will also run in separate threads but they
>   will **respect the order** that you specified.

But I was not able to find out what this order should be reliant on. Using the same testng.xml file along with a sample code to reproduce a possible bug If I am not mistaken could be  -

```
@Test(groups = "A")
public void test1() {
    System.out.println("In 1 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Assert 1 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    Assert.assertTrue(false); // making sure this fails
    System.out.println("Out 1 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

@Test(groups = "B")
public void test2() {
    System.out.println("In 2 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Out 2 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

}

@Test(groups = "B", dependsOnMethods = "test1") //notice the dependsOnMethods(hard dependency)
public void test3() {
    System.out.println("In 3 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Out 3 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

Producing the **OUTPUT** -

> ```
> Assert 1 pool-1-thread-1
>
> java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]
> Expected :true
> Actual   :false
>
>   at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
>   at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:513)
>   at org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:42)
>   at org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
>   at TestOrder.test1(TestOrder.java:18)
>
> In 2 pool-1-thread-2
> In 1 pool-1-thread-1
> Out 2 pool-1-thread-2
> In 3 pool-1-thread-3
> Out 3 pool-1-thread-3
> ```

Comment: It sounds like a bug. Could you open an issue on http://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues ?

Comment: Issue opened here: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1287

Answer (score 1):

Appreciate the point noticed here. Went through the documentation looking for what [parallel running](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests) actually does it convey  -

> **parallel="methods"**: TestNG will run all your test methods in separate
>   threads. Dependent methods will also run in separate threads but they
>   will **respect the order** that you specified.

But I was not able to find out what this order should be reliant on.

So tried looking further and found this [dependencies with annotations](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-with-annotations) article -

> - **Hard dependencies.** All the methods you depend on must have run and
>     succeeded for you to run. If at least one failure occurred in your
>     dependencies, you will not be invoked and marked as a SKIP in the
>     report.
> - **Soft dependencies**. You will always be run after the methods
>     you depend on, even if some of them have failed. This is useful when
>     you just want to make sure that your test methods are run in a certain
>     order but their success doesn't really depend on the success of
>     others. A soft dependency is obtained by adding "alwaysRun=true" in
>     your @Test annotation.

For the `dependsOnGroup` example it reads

> *In this example, method1() is declared as depending on any group
>   matching the regular expression `"init.*"`, which guarantees that the
>   methods serverStartedOk() and initEnvironment() will always be **invoked
>   before** method1().*

So the order of invocation is defined by you in the question but then the execution is not dependent on the success or failure of the other group.

---

But I guess during all this research and trial, I could find another point where I could see the `"parallel=methods"` executing tests irrespective of the hard dependencies too. Have updated the question with a reproducible code as well. Additional points -

1. Even if I change the parallelism to `test` level it wouldn't work.

   ```
   <test name="Test" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
   ```
2. Adding `priority` to methods to define the order explicitly helps but that should not be related to the fact of parallelism I suppose.
3. Of course, the most noticeable point here is, reducing the sleep in `method1` to `Thread.sleep(2000)` makes sure the execution order prevails as expected.

**Disclaimer** - *Though this is not serving as the answer to the current problem, would remove it once there is one posted to solve it.*

***Edit*** -  Date 16 January  2017
This is now an [Open issue in testng library here](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1287) and was fixed with [this PullRequest](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/1290) in code.